# Open hyper links in MS Outlook

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, hyperlink, outlook

When I ckick on the link in my MS Outlook 2010 message it opens in one of my launched IE browser but in what exactly launched and in what tab it's unknown.
Who can advice, how is it possible set up to open all links in new IE process (program) ?

Thanks.

Comment: Good question, but it's not programming related. This is better asked on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour is to open a new tab in your most recently active IE browser window. It's actually up to IE as to how links sent from outlook or other programs are handled.

If you go into internet options, on the "General" tab, at the bottom in the "Tabs" section, click "Settings". The last section on this dialog controls how links sent from other programs are handled. You can select "A new window" here.

[image]